# How can I get the path for the last created file in a directory using Ruby?

Tags: windows, ruby, file

How can I get the path for the last created file in a directory using Ruby?

Comment: For people looking to find the most recently modified folder in directory, go here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207246/how-can-you-find-the-most-recently-modified-folder-in-a-directory-using-ruby

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this is fairly brief:

```
Dir.glob(File.join(path, '*.*')).max { |a,b| File.ctime(a) <=> File.ctime(b) }
```

Comment: You may want to change the file pattern to '*' unless all your files always have extensions. Please also be aware that files beginning with  . will not be considered

Comment: The shorthand version : `Dir[File.join(path, '*.*')].max_by(&File.method(:ctime))`

Answer (score 2):

```
Dir.entries("testdir").reject{|f| f== '.' || f=='..'}.sort_by{|f| File.ctime(f)}.last
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the dir class to list all files and check the ctime or atime of the file object (ctime is the time the file was changed the last time, atime is the time the file was accessed the last time)

```
Dir.foreach("testdir") {|f| puts File.ctime(x) }
```

Comment: How do I order the foreach? I only want the file path with the most recent ctime.

Comment: using sort_by{ |f| f.ctime(f)}

Answer (score 0):

Dir.glob(root_path + "*.*").map{ |file| [file,File.ctime(file)]}.max.first

Answer (score 0):

I added this method to my `supermanpatches.rb` file inside of `railsapp/config/initializers` to open my latest generated migration (in TextMate) without having to copy and paste the filename or anything like that:

```
def latestmigration
  `mate db/migrate/#{Dir.glob(File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'migrate', '*.rb')).max { |a,b| File.ctime(a) <=> File.ctime(b)} }`
end
```

‡: (FYI for ruby/rails beginners, initializer code is omnipresent and requires no class-to-filename scoping to be accessible from anywhere within rails)

NOTE: With windows (or mac) you could use the `vim` command instead of the `mate` command, and sublimetext can be configured to do this too, I think its called the `subl` command. `mate` & `subl` don't work by default though I think, so you have to set that up first