# How can you find the most recently modified folder in a directory using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file, find, directory

How can you find the most recently modified folder (NOT A FILE) in a directory using Ruby?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
Dir.glob("a_directory/*/").max_by {|f| File.mtime(f)}
```

`Dir.glob("a_directory/*/")` returns all the directory names in `a_directory` (as strings) and `max_by` returns the name of the directory for which `File.mtime` returns the greatest (i.e. most recent) date.

Edit: updated answer to match the updated question

Comment: I'm actually looking for how to find the most recently modified folder rather than file, so File.new throws and error, and there is no Dir.mtime

Comment: @Sam: `File.new` does not appear anywhere in my code and `File.mtime` works just fine with a directory name as an argument. Don't try to "fix" my code, it works as-is.

Comment: This is really close to working but Dir.glob() returns directories AND files, and I only want directories. I found that
Dir.glob("*").delete_if{|entry| entry.include? "."}.max_by{|f| File.mtime(f)}
works for this, but it assumes that none of your directories have periods in them...

Comment: @Dasmowenator: `Dir.glob("*")` includes files and directories, `Dir.glob("*/")` only includes directories (notice the trailing `/`).

Answer (score 1):

Find the most recently modified directory in the current directory:

```
folders = Dir["*"].delete_if{|entry| entry.include? "."}
newest = folders[0]
folders.each{|folder| newest = folder if File.mtime(folder) > File.mtime(newest)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding off of sepp2k's answer a bit to add recursively checking all subdirectories for those coming across this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
if ARGV.count != 1 then raise RuntimeError, "Usage: newest.rb '/path/to/your dir'" end

Dir.chdir(ARGV[0])
newest_file = Dir.glob("**/").max_by {|f| File.mtime(f)}

if newest_file != nil then
puts newest_file.to_s + " " + File.mtime(newest_file).to_s
else
puts "No subdirectories"
end
```

and use this instead if you want all files and not just directories:

```
Dir.glob("**/*")
```