# How to find most recently modified file in a remote directory (via ssh)?

Tags: ruby

I found this answer helpful:

[How can you find the most recently modified folder in a directory using Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207246/how-can-you-find-the-most-recently-modified-folder-in-a-directory-using-ruby)

But what I need is to do the same for a remote directory (via SSH). What is the easiest way to do this in Ruby?

Here's what I have so far:

```
paths = (IO.popen("ssh -A user@yo.mammas.house.com ls /install/")).read.split("\n")
```

I only want these folders:

```
if p =~ /^release-MC-.*$/
```

I'm currently parsing the result of the `ls` command, splitting on new lines, matching on the regex and the next step is to build a hash of the date string embedded in the folder name. I really don't want to have to do this last step but it will work.

Is there a better way?

Comment: How are you accessing the remote directory?

Comment: `Net::SSH`?  Or `ssh` via backticks?  Or something else?  What have you tried?

Comment: Ramy: I mean what @Nick asked.

Comment: You haven't tried anything yet? Show us your attempt to solve this.

Comment: I've tried fuse. but I can't mount (just says `remote host disconnected`). I'm now just sending an ls via ssh but the parsing is tedious.

Comment: `IO.popen` is awful heavyweight for what you need to do. `%x` or backticks is sufficient when all you want is to capture STDOUT from the connection. Also, `/^release-MC-.*$/` can be reduced to `/^release-MC-/` and accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is less a Net::SSH question as it is "What command can I issue to find the most recently modified file?"

SSH connections can issue a command, so once you know what command to send, or execute, you're done. I'd look at:

```
ls -Alt path/to/files | sed -n '2p'
```

Fleshing out something more usable results in:

```
require 'net/ssh'

HOST = 'hostname.domain'
USER = 'user'
PASSWORD = "password"

output = Net::SSH.start(HOST, USER, :password => PASSWORD) { |ssh|
  ssh.exec!('ls -alt . | grep pattern_to_find') 
}

puts output
```

Which, after filling in the fields with the right values and running it, connected to one of my hosts at work and returned something like:

```
drwxr-xr-x  11 xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx    4096 Oct  2 16:20 development
```

If you have multiple hits you need to retrieve, either expand the pattern after `grep` or discard the pipe to `grep` and parse your resulting output in Ruby once the command returns. You can also discard the `t` flag from `ls` if you want to sort locally, though it's a better idea to offload as much of the processing to the far-side host, rather than have it return a huge glob of data and process it locally. The less you return, the faster your overall code will be.

Comment: hmm...this seems close but what I need is the most recently modified folder that matches a regex. Sorry I wasn't clear on that.

Comment: Um... It's *REALLY* important to specify *ALL* the criteria when you ask a question.