# With Vim Rails, can you create a new migration file and open it in one go?

Tags: ruby, vim, textmate

Using vim with the Rails plugin, can you create a migration file and then open the file in one go?

Was this possible with textmate also?

Comment: do you mean with the [rails](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567) plugin?

Comment: yes sorry the rails plugin is what I meant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [rails.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567) and then do something like:

```
:Rgenerate migraton add_foo_to_bar
```

The plugin will open the migration generated file, that's exactly what you want. I can't speak for textmate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Vim, but this is the only question like this on SO. So here's how I'm doing this from the rails command line (these instructions would work for vim or any other editor that can open text files from the command line):

I added this method to my `supermanpatches.rb` file inside of `railsapp/config/initializers` to open my latest generated migration (in TextMate) without having to copy and paste the filename or anything like that (got some help from this question: [How can I get the path for the last created file in a directory using Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166161/how-can-i-get-the-path-for-the-last-created-file-in-a-directory-using-ruby/19732419#19732419))

```
def latestmigration
  `mate #{Dir.glob(File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'migrate', '*.rb')).max { |a,b| File.ctime(a) <=> File.ctime(b)} }`
end
```

‡: (FYI for ruby/rails beginners, initializer code is omnipresent and requires no class-to-filename scoping to be accessible from anywhere within rails)